# Mysql join tables without repeating rows which belong to same row

Tags: mysql, join, aggregate-functions

I've been trying to figure this out for hours. But with no luck.

This works perfectly, but the problem i got with these. For e.g if same report has more than 1 comment, then this will create new row instead of unite the comments with same row with the report.

How it's now:

```
{"text":"My first report","comment":"Great Report","display_name":"Xavier"},
{"text":"My First report","comment":"Do you call this a report?","display_name":"Logan"}
```

How i would like it to be:

```
{"text":"My first report","comments":[{comment: "Great Report","display_name":"Xavier"}, {comment: "Do you call this a report?","display_name":"Logan"}],
```

Current Setup

```
Report
ID | User_ID | TEXT |
15   3        My first report

Users
ID | DISPLAY_NAME |
1   Xavier
2   Logan
3   Cyclops

Report_Comments
ID | User_ID | Report_ID | TEXT as comment |
3   1          15         Great Report
4   2          15         Bad Report
```

How it should be:

```
Report_Comments
ID | User_ID | Report_ID | TEXT as comment |
3   1, 2          15         Great Report, Bad Report
```

```
SELECT report.text, 
       report_comments.text AS comment, 
       users.display_name 
FROM   report 
       LEFT JOIN users 
              ON users.id = report.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN report_comments 
              ON report_comments.report_id = report.id 
WHERE  report.user_id = :userId
```

Comment: *...unite the comments...* how? Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: I've updated with example of current behaviour and expected result

Comment: You present your sample data and expected results as json objects, but the query you posted returns a resultset in a tabular format with rows and columns. So which is it that you want?

Comment: The sample data i posted, it's how i how it show in the php file when i echo it with json_ecode. But i would it work like i posted.

Comment: As I said, a said a sql query will return rows and columns. Can you post your expected results as such?

Comment: I've updated in SQL format, but hopefully it will output as i would like in Json or even close to that

Comment: There is no `report.user_id` column. I had to rearrange the joins. See my answer.

Comment: My fault there is `report.user_id` i was able to try before the edit. And it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it if you group by report and use GROUP_CONCAT() for user ids and names and comment texts:

```
SELECT r.text, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.user_id ORDER BY c.ID) AS User_ID,
       GROUP_CONCAT(u.display_name ORDER BY c.ID) AS User_Name,
       r.id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.text) AS comment
FROM   report r
       LEFT JOIN report_comments c ON c.report_id = r.id
       LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = c.user_id 
-- WHERE  report.user_id = :userId       
GROUP BY r.id, r.text
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=50c9d8de1f58768614528f7412577805).
Results:

```
> text            | User_ID | User_Name    | id | comment                
> :-------------- | :------ | :----------- | :- | :----------------------
> My first report | 1,2     | Xavier,Logan | 15 | Bad Report,Great Report
```

Comment: This works great, but my question is. Is it possible to achive the way i trying with the json format? Or is it another topic?

Comment: This is why I asked if you want the results in json format. You posted a query that has nothing to do with json. If you want strictly json results then ask a question where you mention that and post all the relevant code.

Comment: Oh i thougt they went hand by hand. My fault, but i've learned something new. So i'm thankful for that